# Have to save twice for CSV file

Tags: excel, excel-2007

After I edit the existed CSV file, click save will prompt a message dialog "some feature in your workbook might be lost if you save it as CSV (Comma delimited)". Then I click "Save". After that when I click "Close" to close the CSV, prompt message dialog again "Want to save your changes to 'sample.csv' ". Why I have to save twice? How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/disable-annoying-prompt-when-saving-as-csv-in/dcab7c3a-4260-45e8-b4b5-c0c3d6a5ab67

Comment: Not work. After I assign macro. Return to excel, whole page is grey color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Why I have to save twice?` That unfortunately is an inbuilt feature which AFAIK you cannot change.

Even I find that annoying. In your scenario if you click on `No` the 2nd time you get the popup, it will not create any problems because your file is already saved. Feel free to close that dialog box. There is no setting that you can change to avoid this behavior.

Btw, this behavior can be replicated in a normal workbook as well.

1. Create a new workbook. Type anything in Sheet1
2. Save it as a Csv. The first prompt that you will get is

   [image]
3. The 2nd prompt that you will get it

   [image]
4. Now close the file without making any changes. You will `still` get this prompt

   [image]

This annoying feature cannot be turned off. You have to live with it. You can simply click on `Don't Save` or close the dialog box. Don't worry, your file is already saved as a `CSV` :)

Comment: But how about using Macro?

Comment: It is no point using a macro if you are manually saving the file. Because you will have to copy the macro everytime to a new workbook.